# Get content from a REST API Service in C#

Tags: c#, json, dotnet-httpclient

I`d like to get a content from an REST API service. I have an Uri that returns me a JSON content. Like this example below:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "2",
        "type": "people",
        "attributes": {
            "email": "localhost@localhost.com",
            "name": "My Name",
            "gender": "M",
            "cpf": null,
            "cnpj": null,
            "rg": null,
            "person-type": "NATURAL"
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code, but I don't know, I can't get the content. Someone could help me. I just like to get this content in my code behind.

```
async Task InitializeUserData()
    {
        var AppToken = Application.Current.Properties["AppToken"];
        var AppUid = Application.Current.Properties["AppUid"];
        var AppClientHeader = Application.Current.Properties["AppClientHeader"];

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.xxx.com/v1/profile");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Access-Token", AppToken.ToString());
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Client", AppClientHeader.ToString());
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("uid", AppUid.ToString());
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("").Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Your json is not valid.

Comment: The base address should be ˋhttps://api.xxx.com/v1ˋ and then call *var response = await client.GetAsync("profile/2");*

Comment: *I cant get the content* does not help us understand the issue. Please be more specific. Are you getting an exception or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **must** place a slash `/` at the end of `BaseAddress` URI,and must not place a slash at the begining of your relative URI , as in the following example.

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.xxx.com/v1/profile/");
//https://api.xxx.com/v1/profile"/"

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("").Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Reference MS's Docs [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Answer (score 0):

I see your error was already taken care of, but I'd recommend you to take a look at Flurl. It will make your life easier while writing this requests, and will make your code way more beautiful than 
using HttpClient (because of its fluent syntax).

Read more at 
[Flurl's github page](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl) and [Flurl's documentation](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http/)